# Multi-line plot titles in Pyxplot

Tags: gnuplot, pyxplot

Is it possible to make a multi-line plot title in Pyxplot?  I do understand that the "set title" command accepts a LaTeX string and have tried to inject a newline in many ways.

Ultimately it seems that Pyxplot is just ignoring the newline directive.  For example:

```
set title 'First line$\newline$Second line'
```

will generate a title that reads "First lineSecond line".

Is there a trick to make this work somehow?

I am using Pyxplot 0.9.2.

Comment: You can try putting everything in a `\parbox`, see "10.15 LaTeX and Pyxplot": `set title '\parbox{6cm}{\centering First line\newline Second line}'`. I cannot test it, therefore I just post it as comment.

Comment: Not familiar with Pyxplot but `\newline` should work without math mode. Have you tried simply doing `Line 1\newline{}Line 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Christoph in the comments above:

> You can try putting everything in a \parbox, see "10.15 LaTeX and Pyxplot": set title '\parbox{6cm}{\centering First line\newline Second line}'. I cannot test it, therefore I just post it as comment.

\parbox does seem to do the trick.  I tested this and it did allow me to perform line breaks.

Thanks!